# Параллельное выполнение циклов while в Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, многопоточность

Мне нужно добавить игровое время, которое будет идти в несколько раз быстрее обычного времени, делаю это через цикл while. Все циклы должны работать параллельно, а не поочерёдно. Как это сделать?

Код не дописан, но суть, я думаю, поняли.

```
import time
import progressbar
import random
print("Игра CastleHouse открыта! Версия: beta 0.1!")
for ar in "   ":
    print(ar)
print("- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -")
print("Добро пожаловать в королевство CastleHouse!")
print("Развивайтесь и станьте великим в этом текстовом мире!")
print("Для начала получите информацию о себе командой info.")
print("Чтобы посмотреть команды введите help.")
money = 0
health = 100
force = 1
food = 100
time1 = 0
time2 = 0
while True:
    time2+=1
    time.sleep(0.3)
    if time2==60:
        time1+=1
    if (time1 == 24) and (time2 >= 00):
        time1 = 0
        time2 = 0
while True:
    a = input(">>> ")
    if a == ("info"):
        print("Деньги: "+str(money)+"$")
        print("Здоровье: "+str(health))
        print("Сила: "+str(force))
        print("Еда: "+str(food))
        print("Чтобы начать работу введите job.")

    if a == ("job"):
        raboti = ["Шахта", "Лесопилка"]
        for rabota in raboti:
            print("* "+rabota)
        nc = input(">>> ")
        if nc == (raboti[0]):
            time.sleep(1)
            bar = progressbar.ProgressBar().start()
            for i in range(101):
                bar.update(i)
                time.sleep(0.2)
            bar.finish()
            zarp = random.randint(1,40)
            print("У вас было: "+str(money)+"$")
            money += zarp
            print("У вас стало: "+str(money)+"$")
            health-=5
            food-=5
            print("Вы потратили 5 здоровья и 5 голода.")
        if nc == (raboti[1]):
            print("Вы выбрали работу "+raboti[1])
            print("Начинаем работать...")
            time.sleep(1)
            bar = progressbar.ProgressBar().start()
            for i in range(101):
                bar.update(i)
                time.sleep(0.1)
            bar.finish()
            zarp = random.randint(1,20)
            print("У вас было: "+str(money)+"$")
            money += zarp
            print("У вас стало: "+str(money)+"$")
            health-=2
            food-=3
            print("Вы потратили 2 здоровья и 3 голода.")
    if a == ("help"):
        print("* job - работа.")
        print("* info - информация о себе.")
        print("* help - помощь.")
        print("* stopgame - закончить игру.")
        print("* medic - сходить в больницу.")
        print("* shop - сходить в магазин.")
        print("* time - игровое время.")
        print("* inv - инвентарь.")
        print("* use - использовать.")
    if a == ("stopgame"):
        print("Заканчиваем игру...")
        time.sleep(2)
        health=0
    if health >=101:
        health=100
    if a == ("medic"):
        health = 100
        ranf = random.randint(0,50)
        money -= ranf
        print("Вы сходили в больницу, потратив на лечение "+str(ranf)+"$.")
    if money <= -1:
        print("Вы обанкротились и заболели. На лечение и еду вам не хватает денег.")
        health = 0
    if a == ("shop"):
        print("Вы входите в магазин и видите товары:")
        tovaru = ["Чай", "Аптечка", "Яблоки", "Лотерейный билет"]
    if a == ("time"):
        print(str(time1)+":"+str(time2))

    if health <= 0:
        print("Конец игры. Ваше здоровье упало до нуля.")
        time.sleep(3)
        break
```

Comment: И ещё, весь код, который я нашёл до этого к своей проблеме был с помощью цикла for, что мне не нужно, ведь он в один момент может закончиться.

Comment: Соблюдайте отступы, чтобы код был рабочим :)

Comment: если мой ответ помог с вопросом, то примите его -- "[чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)" :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте модуль `threading`, чтобы создать поток и в него поместите цикл с временем:

```
from threading import Thread

...

time1 = 0
time2 = 0

def time_tick():
    global time1, time2

    while True:
        time2 += 1
        time.sleep(0.3)
        if time2 == 60:
            time1 += 1
        if (time1 == 24) and (time2 >= 00):
            time1 = 0
            time2 = 0

thread_time = Thread(target=time_tick)
thread_time.start()
...
```